# Get QImage Source file path

Tags: qt, qt5, qtquick2

How can I get the resource file path for a `QImage`? For example I have the following code:

QML:

```
    ImageProcessor {
        id: imgProc
    }

    Image {
        id: image
        source: "placeholder.jpg"
    }

    Button {
        id: procBtn
        text: qsTr("Process")
        onClicked: {
            imgProc.processImage(image);
        }
    }
```

QObject code: here I wish to inspect/get the image source file path:

```
void ImageProcessor::processImage(QVariant image)
{
    QImage qImage = image.value<QImage>();
    qDebug() << "Image file path is: " << image.source;
    Mat src = imread(qImage.source, cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
}
```

Comment: Why not simply pass `image.source` to your method?

Answer (score 0):

You can not: the reason is, QImage not necessarily get it content from a file, but could be created dynamically for example by a QPainter.

Another alternative is to extend QImage and save the image path. You may also just save the path somewhere else.